# Как сделать скриншот с удаленного рабочего стола?

Tags: c#, администрирование, vba, powershell, wmi

Допустим, есть 10 IP машин, на которых крутится какой - то процесс, который хочется контролировать.

Можно ли со своей рабочей машины послать какую-нибудь команду, которая бы сделала скриншот и передала его мне на основную машину? Даже достаточно было бы если бы скриншот выложился бы в какое-нибудь общедоступное место, такое как сетевая папка. Возможно ли такое?

В приоритете решение на `VBA` (не путать с`VB.NET`) и без дополнительной установки софта.

Может быть можно решить задачу используя WMI?

Если нативно это сделать нельзя, то какими методами этого можно добиться?

Comment: Я бы поглядел в сторону powershell. Оно вроде может исполнять команды на удаленном ПК

Comment: @tym32167, вроде, PowerShell не входил в стандартный пакет установки Windows 7 и ранее, и начал ставится автоматом на последующих ОС. Ну да ладно... Думаю, что прокинуть PowerShell на другие ПК не проблема.

Comment: Почему то я думал, что он с апдейтами приходит для W7, ну и встроен сразу в старшие версии

Comment: Последний пошик под 7 числится за номером `KB3191566`.

Answer (score 5):

Готовый скрипт для Powershell, позволяющий сделать скриншот, всегда лежит [в центре сценариев Technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/eeff544a-f690-4f6b-a586-11eea6fc5eb8)

Теперь об удаленном запуске. Собственно, сама возможность удаленного запуска должна быть разрешена. Вроде как это можно сделать при помощи PowerShell'овского Enable-PSRemoting-Force. Это запустит службу удаленного управления WinRM и пропишет исключения в брандмауэре. Но можно сделать для всего домена, используя механизм групповых политик.

Как запустить? В голову приходят пара вариантов:

- Самый простой способ. ЕМНИП, начиная с XPюши:

  **wmic /node:"имя_компа" process call create запускаемый_файл**
- Через powershell:

  **Invoke-Command -ComputerName имя_Компа -ScriptBlock {
  запускаемый_файл } -credential имя_пользователя # имя_пользователя - если необходимо**

Можно ещё работать с VB&WMI, но навскидку я не помню, как. Но, думаю, для решения задачи и двух вышеприведённых вариантов достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

для старых машин можно использовать psexec https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec для запуска утилиты.. 
например http://www.irfanview.com/
i_view32.exe /capture=0